# PostGres SQL Update Values based on List of IDs or Primary Keys in another table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have a list of IDs [1,5,8,...].  I also have a table (TableA) that has 100 rows (which matches my list of IDs exactly).  I have another table (TableB) that has tons of rows (2000) and I want to update one column (True/False) based on if the Primary Key exists in TableA's primary keys (or my python list of IDs - which is the same).

Currently I loop through my list of IDs and just do a simply update statement (below is python code):

```
for id in ID_List:
     cur.execute('update TableB set "Column1"=%s where "ID"=%s', (False,id))
```

This works fine - but I am curious if there is a single line code I could use rather than a loop.  Something like:

```
cur.execute('update TableB set "Column1"=False where "ID" in ID_List')
or 
cur.execute('update TableB set "Column1"=False where "ID" in TableA.keys()'
```

and all the rows in the ID_List would update quickly.  I can't use ">" or "<" because the IDs might not all be greater than or smaller than a specific number.  I may want to change IDs (3,6,9) but not (4,7,8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
update TableB set "Column1"=False where TableB."ID" in (select TableA."ID" from TableA)
```